# Property 'fonts' does not exist on type 'Document'?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

i use typescript in vue 
and use document.fonts api
but console this log

```
Property 'fonts' does not exist on type 'Document'
```

Answer (score 4):

Experimental APIs aren't in the lib file.

You can fix it with: `(document as any).fonts`

Answer (score 3):

For me and according to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30984) thread, was enough to install the following package:

```
npm i -S @types/css-font-loading-module
```

And then on the .ts file where you see the error, import the next line:

```
import type { } from "css-font-loading-module";
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to an ambient declaration file, like for example `src/index.d.ts`

```js
type CSSOMString = string;
type FontFaceLoadStatus = 'unloaded'|'loading'|'loaded'|'error';
type FontFaceSetStatus = 'loading'|'loaded';

interface FontFace {
  family: CSSOMString;
  style: CSSOMString;
  weight: CSSOMString;
  stretch: CSSOMString;
  unicodeRange: CSSOMString;
  variant: CSSOMString;
  featureSettings: CSSOMString;
  variationSettings: CSSOMString;
  display: CSSOMString;
  readonly status: FontFaceLoadStatus;
  readonly loaded: Promise<FontFace>;
  load(): Promise<FontFace>;
}

interface FontFaceSet {
  readonly status: FontFaceSetStatus;
  readonly ready: Promise<FontFaceSet>;
  check(font: string, text?: string): Boolean;
  load(font: string, text?: string): Promise<FontFace[]>
}

declare global {
  interface Document {
    fonts: FontFaceSet
  }
}
```